# Isn't rest_do_request() filtered by pre_get_posts() filter?

Tags: rest-api

I'm toying with `rest_do_request()` with the plan to use it for a semi-headless theme (we use it to power a sort of CRM for our clients, using custom plugins with lot of CPTs etc).

I'm experimenting a weird (to me) issue related to the `pre_get_posts()` filter:

- when I call my REST endpoint with a "real" REST remote call (let's say by ajax or Postam), the response is coherent with the rules I setup in the `per_get_posts` filter
- but when I internally call the same REST endpoint with `rest_do_request()` it looks like that `pre_get_posts` is ignored

To me this shouldn't the expected behaviour: if `rest_do_request()` is a way to route a REST request internally, it should be respond in the same way that a "real" remote request.
Someone here can help me understanding?

**Some example code:** (it's just an example. In my real implementation I have lot of CPTs and I'm doing a lot of check in `pre_get_posts`, but the issue is clearly visible even with this little code).

**the pre_get_posts code:**

```php
<?php 
add_action('pre_get_posts','test_pre_get_post_filter');
function test_pre_get_post_filter($query){
    
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish'));

    if(!$query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 7 );
    }

    if( empty($query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ) $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    if( empty($query->get( 'order' ) ) ) $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );

}
```

The code above forces the display of only 7 posts ordered by title ascending (and not the usual WP "out of the box" 10 posts by date descending.

And in fact in the archive I get only 7 posts ordered by title ascending.

**Now add a call with `rest_do_request()` to the same endpoint** (we put it on the same index.php archive file just for simplycity):

```php
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/posts' );

$response = rest_do_request( $request );

if ( $response->is_error() ) {
    // Convert to a WP_Error object.
    $error = $response->as_error();
    $message = $error->get_error_message();
    $error_data = $error->get_error_data();
    $status = isset( $error_data['status'] ) ? $error_data['status'] : 500;
    wp_die( printf( '<p>An error occurred: %s (%d)</p>', $message, $error_data ) );
}

$rest_query_data = $response->get_data();

wp_dump($rest_query_data);
```

**The dump shows 10 posts ordered by date descending, thus ignoring the `pre_get_posts` filter.**

So, to summarize:

- **first question**: Is this the expected behaviour? I'm doing something wrong?
- **second question**: How can I set the query variables that I set in `pre_get_posts` also in `rest_do_request()`?

Comment: Try removing the conditions on changing the query parameters. I'm wondering if one of the requests is specifying a `posts_per_page` and `order` parameters, thus negating the change.

Comment: Yeah @Caleb! removing the conditions solves the issue! Thank you! They were here because I copy-pasted them from my real app code. I use them to provide a sort of "default" behaviour for the custom post, that can be changed with query variables... If I remove the conditionals I have no way to pass query parameters to change (for examplo) the order etc... But at least I understood that rest_do_request() is passing thru pre_get_posts(). Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the conditionals for the `set()` calls will solve the problem. I suspect that the REST request is populating those parameters, and as such the `set()` calls do not occur.

Untested:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'test_pre_get_post_filter' );
function test_pre_get_post_filter( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish' ) );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 7 );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
}
```